# How can I use MySQL variables in subqueries?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I'm trying to run the following query, but it keeps getting "reduced" and failing. Cannot get MySQL to provide any information as to why.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE name IN(SELECT @animal_names);
```

Here's the information underneath the variable and table.

TABLE:

```
mysql> mysql> SELECT * FROM animals;
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | dog     |
|  2 | cat     |
|  3 | penguin |
|  4 | lax     |
|  5 | whale   |
|  6 | ostrich |
+----+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

VARIABLE:

```
mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(QUOTE(name)) INTO @animal_names FROM animals WHERE name LIKE '%%';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

mysql>
mysql> SELECT @animal_names;
+-----------------------------------------------+
| @animal_names                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 'dog','cat','penguin','lax','whale','ostrich' |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ISSUE:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM animals WHERE name IN(SELECT @animal_names);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM animals WHERE name IN(SELECT @animal_names);
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | animals | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    6 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Note (Code 1249): Select 2 was reduced during optimization

MySQL refuses to tell me why the "SELECT @animal_ids" is not working! Is there some MySQL variable that needs to be adjusted for that subquery to work?

This is a test sample. I'm trying to do this on a larger scale with about 800 values in a list. I want the list in a variable so I don't have to do A SELECT query multiple times to DELETE, INSERT, SELECT the values I need across multiple databases and tables.

Obviously this can be easily done with a Python or Golang script, but I'm trying to do this in MySQL directly. While I appreciate it, please refrain from offering script-based solutions.

Answer (score 3):

The variable contains ONE string, but to work properly the subquery in `IN()` needs to return different items as multiple rows.

```
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE name IN(SELECT @animal_names);
```

is translated to

```
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE name IN(SELECT '\'dog\',\'cat\',\'penguin\',\'lax\',\'whale\',\'ostrich\'');
```

MySQL variable cannot hold table resultset so this is not directly possible. You would have to create a subquery to extract separate values to rows by joining some counter table and parsing the string. Or you may use [dynamic sql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) which allows to take a string and parse it - that way you would define new variable containing entire select with the IN list filled by your current variable, and then prepare  a statement from that string representation (sort of SQL eval). But probably best would be to just use the query direcly as a subquery instead of filling the variable. Newer version should materialize such independent subquery automatically. For good performance on older versions, you might want to create a temporary table instead and use JOIN and not IN.

Just a note - `GROUP_CONCAT()` is not very safe as there is a limit (variable) to how long string it can return and some results may be lost (with a warning) when the limit is exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM animals
WHERE CONCAT(',', @animal_names, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,\'', name, '\',%');
```

It won't perform fast, but it'll work.

Comment: May fail if the lists are sorted differently.

Comment: @RickJames It could only fail if the elements in the list could have commas next to apostrophes

Answer (score 0):

Build a Stored Routine; in it use `CONCAT` to construct the `SELECT` with the @variable stitched in; `prepare` and `execute`.

Alternatively, if you are using an application language such as PHP, do the stitching in that language.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE FIND_IN_SET(name,(SELECT @animal_names));
```

See the [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) documentation

Comment: This is what I was trying to do.